# How to get multiAddr from js-ipfs node running in browser, ipfs.config.get("Addresses.API") always is empty

Tags: ipfs, js-ipfs

I'm setting up a IPFS Cluster in my local and trying to connect a browser peer(js-ipfs) to it. The cluster will take `bootstrap add <multiAddr>`, but I couldn't get the multiAddr from js-ipfs.

Can anyone help me out here?

js-ipfs code to create a node:

`await ipfs.create() const multiAddr = (await ipfs.config.get('Addresses.API')).toString()`

The `multiAddr` is always "" empty string.

I expected the multiAddr to be available so that I can add a peer in my ipfs cluster node.